Laravel Cashier for Paddle Webhook Event Problem
How do I listen to Cashier RecievedWebhook Event for these events
Transaction Completed
Subscription Created
Subscription Updated
Subscription Canceled
And secondly when I create the checkout session can I pass my custom data, and get it via paddle webhook payload example
$checkout=$user->checkout([plan_id])
->returnTo(route("home"));
Is it possible I pass my custom data here and then get it wen paddle do a post to my webhook.
And the last is it unusual that after a successful transaction, whether subscription, cancelation etc that paddle post to ur webhook more than one time.
Because I am getting more than one post request from paddle after a successful transaction, I am using Ngrok, so I don't know if it is Ngrok or what.

I am not sure what are you trying to do. From the code you posted why do you think anything will be logged when the code are almost all commented out?

Stack overflow cut the of the question from the beginning, and I don't know how to edit it.
